# lightdm and desktop session control by command line

Tags: linux, ssh, login-screen, desktop-environments

Using linux desktop systems (lightdm login manager, openbox, lxde or unity desktops), how can I enter and exit sessions (eg. log in from lightdm and log out from the desktop session) by command line, maybe even over SSH?

For example, I like to log out from an LXDE session and then log into an Unity session on a machine that does not have mouse nor keyboard attached by SSH.

Comment: You should clarify better what is your real case. How can you locally write something by command-line without an input device? If there is another input device, different from keyboard and mouse, you should say. For the second part/question - to graphical login/logout _from_ a machine with keyboard and mouse _on_ a machine that has not - the more appropriate way is a _"remote desktop software"_ as per the answer below. You can also redirect for example the graph session via ssh with `ssh -X`, `xhost +`, then let start  the session manager `sudo service lightdm restart` and operate from remote.

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for, it is a remote desktop software <sup>[[rds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_desktop_software)]</sup>.
On the machine without keyboard you will run the server, on the other the client.
There are many <sup>[[1](https://www.nomachine.com/)],[[2](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/7-of-the-best-linux-remote-desktop-clients-716346)]</sup> that can change in time. A good start can be the free version of nomachine <sup>[[1](https://www.nomachine.com/)]</sup>

To exit from a simple session instead, you have to find the relative command and invoke it even through an ssh connection, e.g.  in gnome:

```
gnome-session-quit --logout --no-prompt
```

Remember that you can always make restart the login manager with commands like `sudo service lightdm restart`, or `stop` and after `start`, but this will close the whole `lightdm` and not only your current session.

Instead to run from remote a graphic application it is enough to connect with `ssx -X`  to enable the X11 forwarding, or `-Y`, and run the command.

Comment: Ah, so to do a session logout, I have to use a dekstop-specific command? Is there any unspecific variant, like kill the window manager of the current X display :0 or something like that?   And how to relogin again? I mentioned that lightdm will do auto login on boot up, but not if a session was closed of course, it presents the greeter then.

Comment: Install nomachine (or another remote desktop software). That is what you really need. `:-)`. It compresses the _flux_ and allows to effectively use (remotely) that machine. The others are partial variants that will not fulfill your needs. You can always kill the windows manager, better with `sudo service gdm restart` that with `pkill gdm` or `pkill -9 gdm`... but it will remain the problem to do a new login. Again install nomachine (or another remote desktop software), it is what you are searching for.

Comment: But would a remote desktop software not be killed if I exit the current session? VNC and Teamviewer for example would exit.

Comment: A remote desktop software is usually able to suspend your current session and to resume it even from a different location. It is something like if you _log in that remote sessions_ that logs for you in the normal one... choose and try. :-)

Comment: The remote session will stay open if I log out of the graphical session, maybe even closing X? Teamviewer and VNC wouldn't do that. The remote deamon runs inside the current session and will exit if the session is closed of course.

Comment: It shouldn't. To be sure you have to try it. BTW, with `pstree $(pgrep Xorg ) -s -h` I have `init───lightdm───Xorg`,  with pstree $(pgrep nxnode ) -s -h` instead
`init───nxserver.bin───nxnode.bin─┬─nxclient.bin───3*[{nxclient.bin}]` similar output with nxserver,   They doesn't seem to cross each other.  It's more simple if you install on a node and  you do your tests. BTW a remote desktop allows you to create a window that is the _graphical mirror_ of the session on the remote machine. It can be windowed or fullscreen. Usually it runs under the local X. The server on the other side manage it.

Comment: Also question was about login/out the graphical session by *command line*

Comment: It depends from the _graphical session_: e.g.,  as answered above, for gnome-like ones `gnome-session-quit --logout --no-prompt` to logout. For the login it is unusual. If no x is up you can do `startx`. You will not login you will be directly "in".

Comment: Usually after log out, the "display manager" will be visible. Where you can change user / session type and log in again. The question is about how to do this programatically, eg. by an ssh terminal connection to the system. Without touching the system, and without using this desktop remotely.  Just have the computer "magically" log out, and in again with a different session type (eg. Gnome vs. LXDE) by a remote connection on ssh. ssh is not used to use the desktop itself before or after. Just to initiate the logout and login.

Answer (score 0):

After days trying all solutions suggests, the only one that worked for me was:

> killall Xorg

Comment: This would restart the login I guess, leaving you at the login screen, or going into the default session again, if autologin ist on. So you can't change the session by this alone.

Comment: @Mentor Did you try something like `sudo service lightdm stop` changing `lightdm` and `stop` with your desktop manager and the admitted options (start stop restart...)? BTW it is better to exit before from the session (e.g. under kde you can exit with `qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 0 0`... note that changing the numbers you will have a shutdown or a reboot... see the `man`) .

Answer (score 0):

If using systemd, you may use `loginctl`, the systemd login manager, to log out of any desktop session from the CLI over SSH.

In your example, use `loginctl list-sessions` to identify ID of the LXDE session, and then `loginctl terminate-session ID`.

But specifics to then start a Unity (or other) session over CLI SSH I imagine would depend on the desktop manager, e.g. lightdm (which might possibly autostart a greeter depending on the config). Someone else can answer that. Or you could possibly launch the session specific command with the right env vars, e.g. `X=:0 openbox-session`, but this may lack session management.